# Remove/hide the long connecting line in plotting GeoJSON linestring using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, linestring

I encounter this long connecting line when plotting a GeoJSON linestring.
How do I hide/remove this connecting line?

When I plot it in linestring:

[image]

When I plot it manually (slower than using linestring):

[image]

```
<Map
  style={{ height: "400px", width: "100%" }}
  zoom={1.5}
  center={[
    this.state.passes.coordinates[0][1],
    this.state.passes.coordinates[0][0]
  ]}
  scrollWheelZoom={false}
  maxBoundsViscosity={1.0}
  maxBounds={bounds}
>
  <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
  <GeoJSON
    color="red"
    data={this.state.passes}
    onEachFeature={function(feature, layer) {
      layer.on("click", onLineClick);
      layer.bindPopup(createPopupContent(feature));
    }}
  />
  <Marker position={this.state.marker} icon={iconSatellite} />
</Map>
```

Comment: Which part of the line you are not satisfied with? Can we see (at least parts) of source GeoJSON?

Comment: I edited my question and added images to show that the horizontal line is what I want to remove. Thanks.

Comment: It's a consequence of satellite path crossing the meridian. You can get a hint how to solve this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697248/display-geojson-with-leaflet-that-spans-the-180th-meridian

Comment: Make the line multi-part by identifying the segment which crosses +/-180 longitude, and add stop/start points exactly on the date line.

Comment: @Vince There were at least two more comments here. Where did they disappear?

Comment: @TomazicM No idea. Owners can delete (and edit within 5 min). Moderators can delete or edit any time. Anyone can flag comments as "not kind".

Comment: @Vince I was just curious. In my comment I mentioned schema error in nonworking KML and then Sarah commented that she removed offending reference and that it helped.

Comment: All comments are nominally temporary, so a round-trip that corrects an issue could be trimmed without fundamentally changing the question. I'm not a moderator, so I don't have to sweat those details.